# Redirect PHP Page Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

```
<form action="" method="POST" onClick="submit" name="Formular">
<font face="Arial">VID:</font>
<input type="text" name="ID" size="6">
<input type="submit" value="Go" name="B1">
</form>
<?php //Form.php
//ID
if(isset($_REQUEST['ID']) && is_numeric($_REQUEST['ID']))
{
header("LOCATION: http://www.site.org/members/person/details.asp?Id=".(int)$_REQUEST['ID']);
exit;
}
?>
```

Using this form I want to do an iFrame or open a new window in JavaScript. How can I do that?

Comment: Java?  You mean JavaScript?  (Java is to JavaScript as car is to carpet.)

Comment: @RocketHazmat That is an amazingly spot on quote.

Comment: @RocketHazmat That quote is way more useful than this question.

Comment: Great quote, @RocketHazmat!

Comment: @RocketHazmat: I've also heard "as 'ham' is to 'hamster'".

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use a JavaScript redirect instead of a php redirect, change this:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['ID']) && is_numeric($_REQUEST['ID']))
{
header("LOCATION: http://www.site.org/members/person/details.asp?Id=".(int)$_REQUEST['ID']);
exit;
}
```

to this:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['ID']) && is_numeric($_REQUEST['ID']))
{
?>
<script>
self.location='http://www.site.org/members/person/details.asp?Id='+<?=$_REQUEST['ID']?>;
</script>
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['ID']) && is_numeric($_REQUEST['ID']))
{
?>
<script>
window.location='http://www.site.org/members/person/details.asp?Id='+<?=$_REQUEST['ID']?>;
</script>
<?php
}
```